# log4net doesn't work in asp.net mvc5 project

Tags: log4net

I followed the steps in the following link [adding log4net to your mvc project](http://www.oakwoodinsights.com/adding-log4net-mvc-site/), but it doesn't work, can someone help me?

Update: I build a asp.net  mvc5 project, follow the steps of above link. at last I find nothing in SqlServer table. Am I missing something? does anyone know?

Comment: I try this in asp.net, it works. But in asp.net mvc5, I cannot see anything in db.

Comment: look up SSCCE , and look around stack. you have to show more efforts

Answer (score 2):

Despite lacking details about how you've configured log4net, you can enable internal logging to help determine where your problem lies.

Add this **appSetting** to your `web.config`

```
<add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
```

Add this **trace listener**, also to your `web.config`

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <trace autoflush="true">
    <listeners>
      <add 
        name="textWriterTraceListener" 
        type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" 
        initializeData="C:\tmp\log4net.log" />
    </listeners>
  </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

This will log the internal **log4net** operations to `c:\tmp\log4net.log`.  Inspect that log file to help determine where your problem lies.